# Can Spring Batch be used to fetch response from REST API

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, httpclient

I have a Spring boot REST App which Encrypts the data and posts on to another REST application (Vault) which encrypts and stores the sensitive data and return a reference key for the same. This key is then stored in the client application. Right now I have used multiple threads to post the data using HttpClient  and fetch the reference key. Can I Use Spring batch to do the same? All the sample application available for Spring Batch are using it to process CSV. Can It also be used to process data through REST API.

Comment: If it is a single REST call, why dont you create a Tasklet-based step?. Tasklet has a simple interface (a single `execute` method) where you can put your call (e.g. using Apache HttpClient). You can find more at the official [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/step.html#taskletStep)

Comment: Spring batch is just an (advanced) job manager. You can have it execute any job you like including any REST interactions (with `RestTemplate` or `WebClient`). Just implement your custom `ItemReader`/`ItemWriter` and configure your job to use them.